# delete and update specific row in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.In my view page I am showing the data from database in a table i have two buttons in table to edit and delete the row..I want to delete a specific row from database through id.

```
## view




                    <thead>
                         <tr>
                              <th>#</th>
                              <th>First Name</th>
                              <th>last name</th>
                               <th>Email</th>
                         </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($records); ++$i) { ?>
                              <tr>
                                   <td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>

                                   <td><?php echo $records[$i]->fname; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $records[$i]->lname; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $records[$i]->email; ?></td>
                                    <td><button name="edit">Edit</button></td>
                                    <td><button name="delete">Delete</button></td>
                              </tr>
                         <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>



----------
## Controller ##

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {


        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
    public function register()
     {
        $this->load->view("register");

     }
    public function receive()
    {
        $fname= $this->input->post("fname");
        $this->load->model('Model');
        $this->Model->insertdata($fname);
        // echo $this->input->post("fname");
        // echo $this->input->post("lname");
        // echo $this->input->post("password");
        // echo $this->input->post("Email");
    }
    public function all_user(){
        $this->load->model('Model');
         $data['records'] =  $this->Model->get_all_users();
        $this->load->view("store_data",$data);

    }
    public function row_delete(){

        $this->load->model('Model');
   $this->mod1->row_delete($id);
   redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}


----------
## Model ##

class Model extends CI_Model{

    public function insertdata($fname)
    {




 $data = array

        ('fname'=> $this->input->post("fname"),

        'lname' => $this->input->post("lname"),
        'email' => $this->input->post("email"),
        'password' => $this->input->post("password"),


        );


    $this->db->insert('register',$data);

    }
    public function get_all_users()
 {
    $query= $this->db->get('register'); 
        return $query->result();

 }
    public function delete_row()
{$this->db->where('id', $id);

$this->db->delete(''); 


    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  And how does your code tie into your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in ur code

```
//view
<tbody>             
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($records); ++$i) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $records[$i]->fname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $records[$i]->lname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $records[$i]->email; ?></td>                                 
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'welcome/row_delete?id='.$records[$i]->id;?>">Delete</a></td>                       <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>                                  
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

make sure u pass the record id to the view and base_url is configured on config file

```
//controller
public function row_delete(){
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id=$_GET['id'];
$this->load->model('Model');
$this->mod1->row_delete($id);
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);}
}

//model
public function delete_row()
{
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->delete('register');
}
```

reference links [here](http://www.freezecoders.com/2012/11/add-list-edit-delete-record-in-database-using-php.html) and [here](http://webrocom.net/create-read-update-delete-records-codeigniter-using-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the parameters to the where function and table name to delete function:

```
public function delete_row()
{
    // Set where
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    // Run query
    return $this->db->delete('register');
}
```

Cheers